# Grid Data Interpolation

Tags: computational-physics, interpolation, b-spline

What are the most sophisticated methods for interpolating a scalar field say Electric or Magnetic Field on a 3-D grid?

I have scalar data on a meshgrid with equal spacing. I would like to use an interpolating method to interpolate those values onto random points I select on the same grid. I think my best bet is using tricubic splines. Am I right? Some of the scalars might not be linear with others being linear though. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is best depends on the interpretation of the values you have on your uniform grid. If they were computed with a finite element method, for example, then there is an underlying function space that dictates what the interpolation ought to be.

Comment: What if that is not known? I understand that knowing the interpolating method used by theprogram i could easily get my data interpolated. What if i dont know it though?

Comment: If you really know nothing, then cubic splines seems like a good choice.